# Switching in between tabs and closing a tab in a window gives error

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Her's what my code basically does(or i'm trying to do). Open a window, open a link from the page, fetch some data from the page and close the tab. The problem lies in closing the tab. Open the 2nd link again and perform the same operation again.

```
  link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 323, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 404, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 195, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 170, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlwt

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

# 0 wait until the pages are loaded
browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it

browser.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493") # Load page
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2 > a")

def test():#test function
    elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content.clearfix > div > fieldset> div > ul > li > span")
    browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it
    for elem in elems:
        print elem.text
    elem1 = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content.clearfix>div>fieldset>div>ul>li>a")
    browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it
    for elems21 in elem1:
        print elems21.text
    return


for link in links:
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.PAGE_UP)
    browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])
    test() # Want to call test function
    browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it
#    browser.quit()
    browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
#    browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: On which iteration does it fail? First, second, something else?

Comment: It fails in the in the 2nd iteration. In the 1st iteration it opens a tab and fetches the data which i want. When i want to close the tab and open the next link. I'm unable to close it...

Comment: @PythonLearner - Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

1. The [`switch_to_window`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) function is used when you working on multiple windows and **not** tabs. Hence, using that function is useless. As per this [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3380), till date, Selenium officially has no support for tabs
2. When you execute `link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')` notice that the `link` element does not belong to the current tab which is displayed. Hence, you should select a random element from the current tab and then call `send_keys` function.

Your `for` should be like this:

```
for link in links:
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.PAGE_UP)
    test()

    #Here, 'r' is the random element
    r = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("h2 > a")
    r.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```